# GitHub PagesでAPIキーを隠蔽したい

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages, github-actions

GitHub Pagesを使用して、下記のようなことを実現したいと考えています。

**【 実現したいこと 】**
　1. アンケートフォーム（html/css/javascript）をGitHub Pagesで公開する（実装済み）
　2. 回答は、Google Sheets APIを通して、限定公開スプレッドシートに保存する
　**3. セキュリティを考慮し、Google Sheets APIのClientIDとAPIkeyは隠す**

項目3を実現するにあたって、Environment secretsという機能に注目しております。
（Setting->Environments->Environment secretsから登録できる環境固有の変数、と認識しています）
この変数を読み込めるようにするには、GitHub Actionsを登録しなければいけないのは理解しています。
ただ、Actionsにはどのように記載すれば良いのかが分からず...。

**【 質問したいこと 】**
　Environment secretsにindex.html内のjavascriptからアクセスするため、
　　a. GitHub Actionsはどのように記載すれば良いですか？
　　b. javascriptからはどうやってアクセスすれば良いですか？

以上、2点をお伺いしたいです。よろしくお願いします。

---

項目aは、envは下記のように記載する（ここが間違っていたら指摘してください）ことを想定しています。

```
env:
 CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.MY_CLIENT_ID }}
 API_KEY:   ${{ secrets.MY_API_KEY }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

大前提としてAPIのkeyはサーバサイドで利用することを想定されており、残念ながらフロントエンドだけで対応することは難しいです。

[GitHub Actions](https://github.co.jp/features/actions)　はソフトウェアを開発するうえで実行されるビルド、デプロイ、テスト、リリースの手動で行っている作業を自動化するためのツールです。

githubで公開してしまうとまずい情報ですがリリース時には利用したい情報を暗号化できます。
そしてリリース時には暗号化されている情報を複合化してリリースできるというものです。

ただし、ここで重要になってくるのはリリース時には複合化された状態でリリースされます。
つまりはjavascriptに直接暗号化した情報を載せてしまっても公開されているJSファイルにはそのまま秘密情報は載ってしまいます。
なので今回の要件では使えません。

先に述べた通りフロントエンド（html+JS+CSS）だけの要件で秘密鍵を扱うことは難しく、残念ながら要件を再検討されたほうがいいかと思います。

解決方法としては
・サーバサイドを利用して実装をする（サーバに秘密鍵を用意して、サーバと通信しながらサーバからgoogleAPIを利用する形）
・googleフォームをおとなしく使う
※若干抜け道ですが[Googleフォームのデザインを自分なりに修正](https://medium.com/@yonemoto/google%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%82%92%E8%87%AA%E7%94%B1%E3%81%AB%E3%83%87%E3%82%B6%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95-f91a617b402b)される方もいらっしゃいます。もちろん自己責任でお願いします。

Comment: ご回答いただき、ありがとうございます。
素人質問で恐縮ですが、例えば、Reactアプリの秘密鍵をどのように扱えば良いか、[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648652/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-github-page)で議論されていますが、同じようなことはできないということなのでしょうか？

Comment: その最もVoteされた回答でも同じことが書いてありますね。簡約「Reactは完全なフロントサイドアプリなので、本当に秘密にしたい場合はサーバサイドを使いましょう。」

Comment: そこは重々承知しています。その上で記載されていることを実際にできればと思ったのですが...。

Comment: 秘密鍵をGithubには公開したくないけど、フロントのソースコードには載せていいということですか？

Comment: そうなりますね。当然、サーバサイドを使えるのが一番なのですが、諸事情で使えないため、できうる限りの対策をしたい、という風に思っております。

Comment: うーん個人的にはフロントに公開するもgithubに載せるもセキュリティリスクが同じですね。玄関の鍵を閉めたところで、窓の鍵が開けっ放しの状態です。

Comment: そうですか...。サーバなし・Googleフォームでは（抜け道を使っても）実現できないアンケートなので、手詰まりです。他の方法を考えます...。